# How to pipe help results to less by default?

Tags: linux, shell, cat, less-unix

I use `"--help"` or `"-h"` a lot. By default it uses `cat` to open help file.  How can i set it to use `less` by default. I want the result of  `"command --help |less"` to be the same as "`command --help"`

Comment: You can use: man <command>

Comment: No man is long and distracts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias for `--help` wouldn't work. Aliases only apply to command names, not to their arguments. I wouldn't recommend a completely invisible solution, anyways. Too much command-line magic can create bad habits.

You could create a help command instead.

```
h() { "$@" --help | less; }
```

```
$ h cat
Usage: cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
<snip>
```

Answer (score 2):

Commands to not default to `cat` they just write to standard output.

Some comments (e.g., `man`) send the output to the application specified by the `PAGER` variable. You can set it to your favourite pager

```
export PAGER=less
```

But this will only work for applications that actually support it.

Otherwise you will have to pipe your commands as in your question.

Comment: no PAGER doesn't work, creating alias may be?  "--help" to be "--help |less"

Comment: Pager does work for the applications that support it (not all).

Comment: doesn't work as solution i meant, not as "you're wrong"